# Is it legal to use old software illegally?

Tags: licensing

In this question, I'm talking about the unsupported or discontinued software or the old versions of programs that are no available to buy on their official websites as there is already newer versions (e.g. MS Office 2007).

I would like to crack those programs to be able to use them without buying them (which was illegal). Is that okay according to the US law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it legal to do something illegal? No.

Those programs are still under copyright and will be for many, many decades to come (for Office 2007 copyright expires 1 January 2127). You can only use them in the way the copyright owner allows which usually includes paying for a license.

The owner of a copyright may not want to licence/sell it anymore: that is their right. If the licences they have sold are transferable you may be able to buy one second-hand.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. how can I buy the software if it's not available on the official website?

Comment: @user2824371 from a third party that still has boxed versions in stock (and is legally allowed to sell them).  Other than that, you don't.  You don't have a *right* to be sold something specifically of your choosing, so if Microsoft don't want to sell you MS Office 2007, and the sales channels have sold out of existing stock, then you either buy the version that *is* available or you go without.